# Puppet trigger resource only if other resource applied a change?

Tags: puppet

I have a `pp` manifest like this:

```
vcsrepo { '/home/pi/pop_machine':
  ensure   => latest,
  provider => git,
  source   => 'https://github.com/kirkins/pop-machine-demo.git',
  revision => 'master',
}

exec { 'npm start':
  command => "/usr/bin/killall electron & /usr/bin/npm start",
  cwd     => "/home/pi/pop_machine/",
}
```

I want the `exec` resource to restart the device application only if the `vcsrepo` resource found an update on github and made changes.

Would this be possible with puppet alone, or should I write a bash script to check the last time the `.git` folder was updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the metaparameter `subscribe` and parameter `refreshonly` with your `exec` resource to accomplish this.

First, use the `subscribe` metaparmeter to establish an ordering relationship of the `exec` on the `vcsrepo` and to also check for a resource change: https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/metaparameter.html#subscribe

Next, use `refreshonly` to instruct the `exec` resource to only apply a change if the `vcsrepo` repo effected a change (vis a vis non-idempotent): https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/types/exec.html#exec-attribute-refreshonly

It would look like:

```
vcsrepo { '/home/pi/pop_machine':
  ensure   => latest,
  provider => git,
  source   => 'https://github.com/kirkins/pop-machine-demo.git',
  revision => 'master',
}

exec { 'npm start':
  command     => "/usr/bin/killall electron & /usr/bin/npm start",
  cwd         => "/home/pi/pop_machine/",
  subscribe   => Vcsrepo['/home/pi/pop_machine'],
  refreshonly => true,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Matt Schuchard's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45924132/378186) answer didn't work for me.  I kept getting an error from puppet because of the "subscribe" in the "exec":

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Could not autoload puppet/type/vcsrepo: Attempt to redefine entity 'http://puppet.com/2016.1/runtime/type/vcsrepo'.
```

But this did work for me:

```
vcsrepo { '/home/pi/pop_machine':
  ensure   => latest,
  provider => git,
  source   => 'https://github.com/kirkins/pop-machine-demo.git',
  revision => 'master',
  notify   => Exec['npm start'],
}

exec { 'npm start':
  command     => "/usr/bin/killall electron & /usr/bin/npm start",
  cwd         => "/home/pi/pop_machine/",
  refreshonly => true,
}
```